# Caching all DNS records

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

An ISP has caching of all DNS records (the same does the public DNS servers, like google and opendns). Whenever you make a DNS query, it asks to the IP address given by my ISP.

**Questions:**
* Can I do the same, to lower the query time and to hide my DNS queries?
* How do I do it?

**Later Edit:**

I understand how a [client->server DNS query](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/09/DNS_in_the_real_world.svg) works. And I know about local OS DNS caching.

My setup is: I have a few clients (computers) that connect to the internet by a linux box (computer as router). The DNS forwarder is `dnsmasq`.

Comment: Why so many downvotes? I have searched the internet and couldn't found anything on that subject. Only about DNS local caching.

Comment: The downvotes are because it isn't really a [valid question](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) for this site -ie, it's not "in a professional capacity" question. I would recommend deleting it and re-asking on a more appropriate site, probably [Super user](http://superuser.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @Ian Macintosh: thanks for clearing that out. there are so many SE websites that I don't know which one to choose.

Comment: For those who downvoted: instead of showing the way (commenting instead of downvoting) it's much easier and "rewarding" to slap (downvote) a user. you could have pointed me in the right direction and I could have ported my question on the more appropriate website. questions like mine will always popup. there is nothing contructive if you don't point out the mistake.

Comment: @machineaddict You're right that questions like yours will always show up, you're wrong about the "rewarding" part. We're generally subjected to self-righteous outrage regardless of the approach used.

Comment: `An ISP has caching of all DNS records (the same does the public DNS servers, like google and opendns).` - No, they don't.

Comment: @Andrew B: `you're wrong about the "rewarding" part`. if you understood my question, then that's where you are wrong. The "rewarding" part is where the user has the power over the others (votes). So they feel good to downvote. It's easier to do harm then good.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I do the same, to lower the query time and to hide my DNS queries?

Firstly an ISP doesn't nessearily know ALL the DNS records, just the ones it looks after and another DNS server to query for entries it doesn't look after - it does cache these referred ones though but only usually on a need to know basis.

But yes you can do this same thing, in fact your client machines do essentially the same thing.

> How do I do it?

Put in a DNS server/s of your own and point your client machine to it - it sounds simple but can get more complex than this. Look at software called 'bind'.

Comment: Just a side note for the OP, doing this will not "hide" anything from your ISP. The only way to do that is for your unencrypted DNS packets to never touch your ISP at all. (and DNS does not provide query level encryption) Sounds like you're really looking for using a VPN and *someone else's* DNS, but that's an entirely separate discussion.

Comment: @Andrew B: that would be lovely if I can't do a full DNS cache.